# Getting the value of a textfield

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am working with a textfield and I want to have the change logged.  I noticed `change` only keeps track of when you submit, so I was using keyup, but this feels kind of hacky because if someone copy and pasted using the mouse into the text field it wouldn't detect it.  Is there a more rigorous way to observe changes in a text field?

```
var textField = document.getElementById('message-input');
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textField, 'keyup')
  .subscribe(_ => console.log(textField.value));
```

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't an issue for Rx it is more of a general DOM question. However, from an Rx perspective, whatever events you end up using you can just merge all the events you are interested in, and use `distinctUntilChanged()` to make sure you don't end up with duplicate events.

```
var keyup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textField, 'keyup', e => e.target.value);
var focus = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textField, 'focus', e => e.target.value);


Rx.Observable.merge(keyup, focus)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: great point, I'm just trying to get a better understanding of implementations of RxJS for DOM monitoring.